# Please make expressions equal to 6 using exactly four 4s

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Background:  I am the source.  I created this puzzle.  This problem belongs in the Mathematical Puzzling section.  If this is not the correct subforum, then I am asking it to be moved.  People have already begun answering with solutions, and it would be nice for them to be able to try to complete the solutions.

---

You must use all four 4s.

You may use addition (+).

You may use subtraction (-).

You may use multiplication, such as with asterisks (*) and/or grouping symbols.

You may *not* use any division.

You may *not* use decimal points.

You may *not* use any concatenation.

You may use grouping symbols, such as parentheses and/or brackets.

You may *not* use any type of factorial signs.

You may use up to four square root symbols, including the use of nested square roots.

You may *not* use exponentiation.

You may *not* use logarithms.

You may *not* use trigonometric functions.

You may *not* use any other numbers, characters, or operations, to include no other roots.

This is in base 10.

*Try to create and post 10 additional --> essentially <-- different solutions.*

Note:  Regarding "essentially different," $\sqrt4*\sqrt4$ is the same
as $\sqrt{4*4 \ }$, for instance.

Also, $\sqrt{\sqrt{4*4 \ } \ }$ is the same as $\sqrt{\sqrt{4}}*\sqrt{\sqrt{4}}$.

Permutations are the same.

---

Here are examples:

$4 + 4 + \sqrt4 - 4 = 6$

$\sqrt4  + \sqrt4 - \sqrt4 + 4 = 6$

$4(4 - \sqrt{4}) - \sqrt{4} = 6$

Comment: This forum usually has one question (or solution) at a time, not $13$ different ones. What about starting with one possibility? Can you explain this with one example?

Comment: $\sqrt{\sqrt{4!-(4 \times \sqrt{4})}} + 4 = 6$, I believe this might be interesting. (Except the fact that factorials are not allowed, what a pity! :-) :-) :-) )

Comment: @Dietrich Burde -- I will attempt to post three examples.

Comment: You only posted $1$ example, not $3$. By the way, formally $-4+4+4+\sqrt{4}$ is a different possibility. Of course, addition is commutative.

Comment: If you can use the "minus"-sign, you have endless results as $4 = -(-4) = -(-(-(-4)))= ...$ :-)

Comment: $$4+\sqrt[4]{4\times4}$$

Comment: @ Dominique -- Those would not be essentially different.  Minus signs could be removed, and you would have it down to a primitive solution.

Comment: @ Etemon - That index of 4 shows you are using exponentiation.

Comment: $\sqrt{4\times 4\times \sqrt{4}+4}$,$\quad \sqrt{4\times 4}+\sqrt{\sqrt{4\times 4}}$,$\quad \sqrt{4\times 4\times 4}-\sqrt{4}$

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni -- Yes on all three of those.  Would you like to openly post those as solutions instead of just showing them in the comments section?

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi -- I am not allowing division.  I moved this problem over to the Puzzling Section.

Comment: That constraint seemed unnatural. I'm out.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi - The reason I am keeping it out is because it adds WAY too many solutions to this.   It gives at least 30 solutions, but I am trying to keep the number of solutions down closer to half of that so it is more manageable.

Comment: [This question at Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/125132/20814).

Answer (score 2):

Some of the possible ways:
$$4 + \sqrt{4} + 4 - 4 = 6$$
$$4 + \sqrt{4} + \sqrt{4} - \sqrt{4} = 6$$
$$4 + \sqrt{4} \cdot \sqrt{4} - \sqrt{4} = 6$$
$$4 + 4 - \sqrt{\sqrt{4}} \cdot \sqrt{\sqrt{4}} = 6$$

Comment: I think associativity is assumed not to yield different solutions, e.g. $4 + \sqrt{4} + (4 - 4) $ is the same solution as $4 + (\sqrt{4} + 4) - 4$

Comment: @Dietrich Burde - Permutations are to be considered the same.  I am looking for essentially different solutions, please.

Comment: Question:  Does $4 + \sqrt{4 + 4 - 4 \ }$ look like a permutation of $4 + 4 - 4 + \sqrt{4 \ }$ to you, or does it look essentially different because it involves a square root?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
&\sqrt{4\times 4\times 4}-\sqrt{4}\\
&\sqrt{4\times 4\times \sqrt{4}+4}\\
&\sqrt{4\times 4}+\sqrt{\sqrt{4\times 4}}\\
&\sqrt{\sqrt{4}}\times\sqrt{4\times 4+\sqrt{4}}\\
&\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4}}\times\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4}}\\
\end{align}